# Simple bash CSV array issue

Tags: arrays, bash, csv

I'm trying to do something fairly simple, and I'm just coming up short. Here is an example variable I'm trying to work with:

```
20,80,443,53
```

The variable is just a string of ports separated by commas. I need to get those into an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `IFS` to `,` and use the read command with a here-string

```
IFS=, read -r -a arr <<<"20,80,443,53"
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"

20
80
443
53
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
#!/bin/bash
v="20,80,443,53"
IFS=, a=($v) # Split
echo ${a[0]} # Display
echo ${a[1]}
echo ${a[2]}
echo ${a[3]}
```

#### Update

Thanks to gniourf_gniourf for pointing out that IFS was modified as the result of the assignment. Here is my *quirky* work around. Now I see why others did things differently.

```
v="20,80,443,53"

PREV_IFS="$IFS" # Save previous IFS
IFS=, a=($v)
IFS="$PREV_IFS" # Restore IFS

echo ${a[0]}
echo ${a[1]}
echo ${a[2]}
echo ${a[3]}
```

Comment: Caution, this will globally set the `IFS` variable! will bite you in the back if you forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var="20,80,442,53"
IFS=, read -ra ary <<< "$var"
printf "%s\n" "${ary[@]}"
```

```
20
80
442
53
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ports=('20','80','443','53');

for e in "${lic4l[@]}"; do
    echo $e
```

I hope this will help and print the ports in the given variable.

Comment: Does this actually answer the question?

Comment: yes it will add all of your ports into an array which later you can use for display actually it will be 

Ports=('20','80','443','53');

for e in "${Ports[@]}"; do
    echo $e

Answer (score 0):

With SED it becomes a one-liner:

```
a=($(sed 's/,/ /g' <<< "20,80,443,53"))

printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"
20
80
443
53
```